# Какой SQL запрос на удаление текста?

Tags: sql

Как удалить текст в ячейке, во всей таблице?

После `.webp` до `Kb` включительно? Их может быть несколько

столбец xfields

СУБД MySQL

```
image|2023-02/разное-название1.webp&#124;1&#124;0&#124;960x720&#124;26.03 Kb||image1|2023-02/разное-название2.webp&#124;1&#124;0&#124;960x720&#124;57.75 Kb||price|3000||color|черный||size|ряд||season|лето|...
```

Comment: Зависит от конкретной СУБД. В общем - регуляркой.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно для приведенных данных достаточно

```
select regexp_replace(xfields,'webp[0-Z&#;.]+ Kb','webp') 
from test
```

Comment: Ошибка #1305. Может из-за версии MySQL 5.7.41-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: Да, жаль. regexp_replace присутствует с версии 8.0

Comment: А если через php сделать, можно как-то?